# Hortonworks CREATE-USER FAILURE The password does not meet the password policy requirements

Tags: hadoop, active-directory, hortonworks-data-platform

Trying to install Hadoop Hortonworks 2.0.6.0 GA release. 

Installation failed ,the installation log file contains the following error

```
CREATE-USER FAILURE: Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0" argument(s): "The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history requirements.
```

I have taken care so that password is not similar to username.
Passwords is 1Lifepo4

Full log is

`WINPKG: Logging to existing log C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopSetupTools\hdp-2.0.6.0.winpkg.install.log
WINPKG: ENV:WINPKG_BIN is C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopSetupTools\
WINPKG: Setting HADOOP_NODE_INSTALL_ROOT
WINPKG: Making HADOOP_NODE_INSTALL_ROOT from system variable: HADOOP_NODE_INSTALL_ROOT = c:\hdp
WINPKG: Setting hadoop user password
WINPKG: Making HDP_USER_PASSWORD from system variable: HDP_USER_PASSWORD = Carbon02
WINPKG: Setting destroy data
WINPKG: Making DESTROY_DATA from system variable: DESTROY_DATA = yes
WINPKG: Setting HDP
WINPKG: Making HDP from system variable: HDP = yes
WINPKG: Setting HBASE
WINPKG: Making HBASE from system variable: HBASE = yes
WINPKG: Setting FLUME
WINPKG: Making FLUME from system variable: FLUME = yes
WINPKG: Setting Environment::CurrentDirectory to C:\Windows\SysWOW64
WINPKG: Current Directory: C:\Windows\SysWOW64
WINPKG: Package: C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopSetupTools\\..\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.0.6.0-winpkg.zip
WINPKG: Action: install
WINPKG: Action arguments: 
WINPKG: Run-WinpkgAction C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopSetupTools\\..\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.0.6.0-winpkg.zip C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages install 
WINPKG: UNZIP: source C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.0.6.0-winpkg.zip
WINPKG: UNZIP: destination C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages
WINPKG: UNZIP: unzipRoot C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.0.6.0-winpkg
WINPKG: Unzip of C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.0.6.0-winpkg.zip to C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages succeeded
WINPKG: UnzipRoot: C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.0.6.0-winpkg
WINPKG: C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.0.6.0-winpkg\scripts\install.ps1 
HDP: Reading HDP layout from C:\Users\asande\AppData\Roaming\hdp_install\clusterproperties.txt
HDP: Ignoring DB_PORT for DB_FLAVOR derby
HDP: Following properties will be exported into the environment
HDP: Property                      Value                                                       
HDP: --------                      -----                                                       
HDP: HDP_DATA_DIR                  c:\hdpdata                                                  
HDP: CLIENT_HOSTS                  ASANDE1                                                     
HDP: SECONDARY_NAMENODE_HOST       ASANDE1                                                     
HDP: NAMENODE_HOST                 ASANDE1                                                     
HDP: OOZIE_SERVER_HOST             ASANDE1                                                     
HDP: OOZIE_DB_PASSWORD             1Lisioco                                                    
HDP: HBASE_MASTER                  ASANDE1                                                     
HDP: RESOURCEMANAGER_HOST          ASANDE1                                                     
HDP: HIVE_SERVER_HOST              ASANDE1                                                     
HDP: FLUME_HOSTS                   ASANDE1                                                     
HDP: HIVE_DB_USERNAME              hiveusr                                                     
HDP: DB_PORT                       1527                                                        
HDP: OOZIE_DB_NAME                 ooziesand                                                   
HDP: ZOOKEEPER_HOSTS               ASANDE1                                                     
HDP: HDP_LOG_DIR                   c:\hadoop\logs                                              
HDP: DB_HOSTNAME                   ASANDE1                                                     
HDP: HIVE_DB_PASSWORD              1Lifepo4                                                    
HDP: OOZIE_DB_USERNAME             oozieusr                                                    
HDP: WEBHCAT_HOST                  ASANDE1                                                     
HDP: HIVE_DB_NAME                  hivesand                                                    
HDP: SLAVE_HOSTS                   ASANDE1                                                     
HDP: DB_FLAVOR                     DERBY                                                       
HDP: HBASE_REGIONSERVERS           ASANDE1                                                     
HDP: Logging to existing log C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopSetupTools\hdp-2.0.6.0.winpkg.install.log
HDP: Logging to C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopSetupTools\hdp-2.0.6.0.winpkg.install.log
HDP: HDP_INSTALL_PATH: C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.0.6.0-winpkg\scripts
HDP: HDP_RESOURCES_DIR: C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.0.6.0-winpkg\resources
HDP: INSTALLATION STARTED 
HDP: Installing HDP @version@ to c:\hdp
HDP: Setting HADOOP_NODE_INSTALL_ROOT to c:\hdp at machine scope
HDP: Copy the cluster layout to install root
HDP: Using user-defined password.
HDP: C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.0.6.0-winpkg\scripts\create_hadoop_user.ps1 -username hadoop -passwordBase64 ****
CREATE-USER: Logging to existing log C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopSetupTools\hdp-2.0.6.0.winpkg.install.log
CREATE-USER: Logging to C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopSetupTools\hdp-2.0.6.0.winpkg.install.log
CREATE-USER: HDP_INSTALL_PATH: C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.0.6.0-winpkg\scripts
CREATE-USER: HDP_RESOURCES_DIR: C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.0.6.0-winpkg\resources
CREATE-USER: UserGroup not provided. Using default UserGroup HadoopUsers.
CREATE-USER: Creating user hadoop
CREATE-USER: Setting password for hadoop
CREATE-USER FAILURE: Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0" argument(s): "The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history requirements.
"

At C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.0.6.0-winpkg\scripts\create_hadoop_user.ps1:88 char:22
+         $user.SetInfo &1
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Write-Log : CRE...h "0" argument( 
    :String) [], RemoteException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

s): "The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the min
imum password length, password complexity and password history requirements.
"
At C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.0.6.0-winpkg\scripts\create_hadoo
p_user.ps1:220 char:11
+     Write-Log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hortonworks document says "Password requirements are controlled by Windows, and typically require that the password include a combination of uppercase and lowercase letters, digits, and special characters."
So you should check the password requirements of your Windows server, it may be changed to something other than the default one.

Comment: At the start menu a search with secpol.msc / Local security policy opens a dialog which contain Account policies . Account policies contain Password Policy. The mistake was, i entered password less than 12 character length specified there. [Details of password policy on windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-password-policy-settings#1TC=windows-7)