# HDP on Windows Server 2012 R2 Single Node Installation Error

Tags: windows, hadoop, installation

I am trying to install Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP) 2.2.6.0 for Hadoop on Windows Server 2012 R2, by following the [Quick Start for a Single Node](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.2.6-Win/bk_HDP_Install_Upgrade_Win/content/ch_quick_start.html), but I am failing.

**Settings**
I am using Virtual Box for the Windows Server 2012 R2. Java, Python, etc. are set. I am running from the Administrator account. I have run the installer using cmd.exe as Admin.

I un-checked "Install Ranger" from the installer. I also ignored this part of the installation (by also un-checking LZO codec in the installer):

> When deploying HDP with LZO compression enabled, add the following three files (in the HDP for Windows Installation zip) to the directory that contains the HDP for Windows Installer and the cluster properties file:
>   - hadoop-lzo-0.4.19.2.2.6.0-2060
>   - gplcompression.dll 
>   - lzo2.dll

The cluster proprieties txt can be found here: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8838912.

**Error**
From the install log, I see this error:

```
CREATE-USER: Creating user hadoop
CREATE-USER: Setting password for hadoop
HDP-PS FAILURE: Write-Log : CREATE-USER FAILURE: Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0" 
HDP-PS FAILURE: argument(s): "The password does not meet the password policy requirements. 
HDP-PS FAILURE: Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history 
HDP-PS FAILURE: requirements.
HDP-PS FAILURE: "
HDP-PS FAILURE: At C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.2.6.0-winpkg\scripts\create_hadoo
HDP-PS FAILURE: p_user.ps1:220 char:2
HDP-PS FAILURE: +     Write-Log $_.Exception.Message "Failure" $_
HDP-PS FAILURE: +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
HDP-PS FAILURE:     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorExcep 
HDP-PS FAILURE:    tion
HDP-PS FAILURE:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptio 
HDP-PS FAILURE:    n,Write-Log
HDP-PS FAILURE:  
HDP FAILURE: Command "C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.2.6.0-winpkg\scripts\create_hadoop_user.ps1 -username hadoop -passwordBase64 **** failed with exit code  1. Output is  "CREATE-USER: Logging to existing log C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopSetupTools\hdp-2.2.6.0.winpkg.install.log CREATE-USER: Logging to C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopSetupTools\hdp-2.2.6.0.winpkg.install.log CREATE-USER: HDP_INSTALL_PATH: C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.2.6.0-winpkg\scripts CREATE-USER: HDP_RESOURCES_DIR: C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.2.6.0-winpkg\resources CREATE-USER: UserGroup not provided. Using default UserGroup HadoopUsers. CREATE-USER: Creating user hadoop CREATE-USER: Setting password for hadoop Write-Log : CREATE-USER FAILURE: Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0"  argument(s): "The password does not meet the password policy requirements. 
 Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history 
 requirements.
 "
 At C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.2.6.0-winpkg\scripts\create_hadoo
 p_user.ps1:220 char:2
 +     Write-Log $_.Exception.Message "Failure" $_
 +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorExcep 
    tion
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptio 
    n,Write-Log     
" 
At C:\HadoopInstallFiles\HadoopPackages\hdp-2.2.6.0-winpkg\resources\Winpkg.Utils.psm1:130 char:9
+         throw "Command `"$command`" failed with exit code  $captureExitCode. Out ...
```

The full install log can be found here: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8838911

**Same problem. Different ppl**
I saw [this problem already on other forums](http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/installation-on-windows-server-2012-failed/) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005736/hortonworks-create-user-failure-the-password-does-not-meet-the-password-policy-r). I have also tried a complex password, I changed the policy in Widows. Nope..

**Help**
Can you help get rid of this error and continue the installation of HDP?